# Django flatpages Do Not Work

Tags: python, django

I'm reading and following the book "Practical Django Projects: Second Edition" and a lot of the book already is out of date to the point where an entire chapter won't work at all. Right now I'm trying to create my first flat page and I'm getting a 404 error.

I'm trying to use the built in 'django.contrib.flatpages' app and I've already created my first flatpage via the admin panel:

[image]

Here's my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',


    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')) #ADDED THIS LINE FOR FLATPAGES
)
```

Here's what I've done to my settings.py file so far:

```
SITE_ID = 1 # REQUIRED FOR 'django.contrib.flatpages'


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages', # ADDED FOR FLATPAGES
    'south',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware', #FOR FLATPAGES
)
```

So that's about all that I've done so far and I'm expecting a "TemplateDoesNotExist at /first-page/" when navigating to like the book says:
http://example.com:1006/first-page/

But instead of that, I'm simply getting a 404 error.

Am I doing this correctly or did a new Django version depreciate the way to make flatpages?

Comment: I'm not sure using a book that was originally written for Django 0.x and then updated back in 2009 for 1.1 is a good idea for learning Django 1.6…

Comment: Actually, these steps seems still correct, even with Django 1.6: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/flatpages/. Try `urls` patterns given on the documentation (the "catchall" method mainly)

Comment: I've tried the catchall, still getting "No FlatPage matches the given query." is there a way to list available URLs to navigate to?? Like if I had no home page, navigated there I'd get an error listing the urls that are accessable, can I get a printed list of flatpages that are accessable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally figured it out, and every resource online doesn't mention this at all. They never even cover this stuff in the entire chapter from the Apress book. Hopefully everyone else from here on out doesn't have to spend 3 hours on this solution.

[image]

So the solution is, make sure that the `SITE_ID` in the `settings.py` file matches the number in the URL of the site when clicking "change site" in the admin panel. As you can see in the image above, for me the number is "4" which is the site ID. So my `settings.py` should look like this:

```
SITE_ID = 4
```

There are many threads like this one where people just say "change it to 1", which is misleading. Make sure the number matches your site ID!

Answer (score -1):

Page 18, at the bottom: "Introducing the Django Template System". Follow the directions to create the template directory, add it to to TEMPLATE_DIRS, and create your template file in that directory. (pages 18-21)

Comment: Already did that, there's no difference since it doesn't try looking for the html in TEMPLATE_DIRS. It stops dead at 404, I'm suppose to set the TEMPLATE_DIRS once I get the  "TemplateDoesNotExist at /first-page/"  error. Not at that step yet.